# Use of Orbeon CE to drive log file analysis (Saxon)

Tags: tomcat, xquery, orbeon, saxon

I am a Orbeon newby. I have a suite of XQuery scripts the execution of which I want to automate. Orbeon looks like a potential solution to implement the process that I have outlined below. Basically I just want to know if Orbeon CE will give me the right support out the box for each stage of the process?

I have a set of raw log files which contain the logged output from some system test cases. Each raw txt log has a matching XQuery module to verify the test and produce a test pass/fail result with supporting data. To achieve this the process I want to implement would look like :-

1. From UI screen upload some raw (txt) system log data to server (Tomcat). Can upload indiviual txt files or zip containing all files.
2. Execute a custom in-house parser executable to convert the raw log data into Output XML. (can either be from uploaded txt file or by initially extracting uploaded ZIP).
3. Execute a grep to further refine XML from step 2
4. Run an XQuery (xq) script (originally written for Saxon) to analyse the XML from 2&3
5. Display the results from the analysis in the UI

Do you think I can quickly achieve this using Orbeon CE & are there any similar examples/tutorials to get me there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly use Orbeon Forms for this. A few comments on how I would do it, using Orbeon Forms:

1. If you want to support a zip file being uploaded, you can then use the [unzip processor](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/processors-zip-unzip#TOC-Unzip-processor) to uncompress the zip file, and access the files it contains. I'd write the UI in XForms, leveraging `xf:upload`. When users submit the form, an `xf:submission replace="instance"` runs, which POSTs the uploaded file to a service, implemented with a pipeline. That pipeline runs the steps 2-4 below.
2. If you have the Java code for this parser already, then you could [call it from XSLT](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.1/extensibility/functions/staticmethods.html), which you run from a pipeline. Otherwise, you could do the parsing directly in XSLT.
3. It should be easy to do a grep on XML data with XSLT.
4. From a pipeline, using the `oxf:xquery` processor, which invokes Saxon's XQuery engine.
5. The pipeline returns the result to the form, which displays it.

Comment: Great @avernet I'm working on it now. Any idea how I would implement a popup that uploads a file and then returns the name of the uploaded file so that I can populate that filename in a table?

Comment: You want to use a "popup" to let users upload the file? If that is really what you need, then you could use Orbeon's dialog control `xxf:dialog`. See: http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-controls/dialog-control

Comment: Thanks. I would need an 'Upload' link that pops up a file select. In fact I created a more detailed description here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857744/uploading-in-orbeon-xforms-with-result-of-upload-displayed-in-table-cell

Comment: OK, then I will follow-up on that other question's page.